# AppDomain unloaded exception

Tags: linq, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a very simple code and I keep getting this warning. I don't understand whats causing it.

> System.Transactions Critical: 0 :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
>   exceptionvstest.executionengine.exeSystem.AppDomainUnloadedException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an
>   unloaded AppDomain

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDbContext()
{
   using(var ctx = new MyDbContext)
   {
        var orders = ctx.Orders.ToList();
   }
}
```